# Place an SVG element over another

Tags: html, svg

I just wonder whether it is possible to place an SVG element over another. Here is my HTML:

```
<svg id="svg" width="950" height="910" style="border: 2px rgb(204, 204, 204); margin-top: 10px;">
  <rect x="348" y="95" width="16" height="16" class="handle" polygonNo="0" pointNo="0"></rect>
  <rect x="582" y="95" width="16" height="16" class="handle" polygonNo="0" pointNo="1" style="
"></rect>
  <polygon points="348,206 598,206 598,106 348,106" id="polygon" polygonNo="1" fill="#8DB0F5"></polygon>
</svg>
```

I want those two rectangles to show over the polygon; I've tried adjusting the `z-index`, but it did not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Change the sequence. Lower level element should be written at the first.

```
<svg id="svg" width="950" height="910" style="border: 2px rgb(204, 204, 204); margin-top: 10px;">
          <polygon points="348,206 598,206 598,106 348,106" id="polygon" polygonNo="1" fill="#8DB0F5"></polygon>
          <rect x="348" y="95" width="16" height="16" class="handle" polygonNo="0" pointNo="0"></rect>
          <rect x="582" y="95" width="16" height="16" class="handle" polygonNo="0" pointNo="1" style=""></rect>
</svg>
```

**Alternate solution**

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 600 600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect x="348" y="95" width="16" height="16" class="handle" polygonNo="0" id="two" pointNo="0"></rect>
  <rect x="582" y="95" width="16" height="16" class="handle" polygonNo="0"  id="one" pointNo="1" style=""></rect>
  <polygon points="348,206 598,206 598,106 348,106" id="polygon" polygonNo="1" fill="#8DB0F5" ></polygon>
  <use xlink:href="#one"/>
  <use xlink:href="#two"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually know changing the order can fulfill this requirement, and I'm seeking a solution with the order unchanged.

Comment: they follow "first element -> "painted" first " so cant apply any external styles after paint. 3.3 Rendering Order

Elements in an SVG document fragment have an implicit drawing order, with the first elements in the SVG document fragment getting "painted" first. Subsequent elements are painted on top of previously painted elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can also manipulate this using JavaScript. Essentially you are appending the 2 rects to the SVG moving them on top of the polygon.

`appendChild()` moves an element it from its current position to the new position and there is no requirement to remove the node from its parent node before appending it again.

Also, you have a border for the SVG without `border-style`. You need to fix that.

```js
let rects = svg.querySelectorAll(".handle");

rects.forEach(r=>{
  svg.appendChild(r)
})
```

```html
<svg id="svg" width="950" height="910" style="border: 2px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); margin-top: 10px;">
  <rect x="348" y="95" width="16" height="16" class="handle" polygonNo="0" pointNo="0"></rect>
  <rect x="582" y="95" width="16" height="16" class="handle" polygonNo="0" pointNo="1" style="
"></rect>
  <polygon points="348,206 598,206 598,106 348,106" id="polygon" polygonNo="1" fill="#8DB0F5"></polygon>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford to separate your SVG element, you can achieve this using CSS positioning as well:

```css
 .top{
position: absolute;
top: 34px;
left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<svg class="top" id="svg" width="950" height="910" style="border: 2px rgb(204, 204, 204); margin-top: 10px;">
  <rect x="348" y="95" width="16" height="16" class="handle" polygonNo="0" pointNo="0"></rect>
  <rect x="500" y="95" width="16" height="16" class="handle" polygonNo="0" pointNo="1" style=""></rect>
</svg>

<svg class="bottom" id="svg" width="950" height="910" style="border: 2px rgb(204, 204, 204); margin-top: 10px;">
    <polygon points="348,206 598,206 598,106 348,106" id="polygon" polygonNo="1" fill="#8DB0F5"></polygon>
</svg>
```

Hope it helps !